# Extremely large spike in training loss that destroys training progress

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am training a super-resolution neural network that takes a low-resolution image and predicts its high-resolution counterpart. However, once in a while (e.g. a few hours), the training loss will spike to an **extremely** large value (e.g. 10^12 times the average loss before spike):

[image]

Inspecting the prediction results after the spike showed that the training progress is basically destroyed and started over, with worse accuracy than even the uninitialized network.

Some details and things I have tried:

- Loss function: I am using L2 loss comparing the predicted images, so there shouldn't be any numerical instabilities. I also used an L2 loss comparing the Sobel gradient of the images.
- Model: I used batch norm in one of the model branches, but the batch size is 8 which isn't too small. The model also has residual blocks.
- Optimizer: I am using Adam with `lr=0.0005, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08`.
- All images in the dataset should all have RGB value within [0, 1], so there shouldn't be any outliers.
- The loss explosion happened halfway through an epoch, so it's not caused by the (possibly smaller) last batch in the dataset.
- I am using gradient clipping, it seemed to make the explosion a bit less frequent but didn't get rid of it.
- I took a look at the checkpoint weights before and after the spike, seems like the L2 norm of the weights had an increase (from about 70 to 110).
- Note that the loss itself also doesn't seem to decrease even before the spike; however visually the result seems to be improving. Not sure if that is a problem on its own.

Comment: How did you choose the amount of gradient clipping to use and the size of the learning rate? It looks like the model is just moving sideways, instead of achieving any kind of a steady decline, so I'm wondering if the larger problem is that the model isn't improving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved, though I am not sure which of the following things I tried was the reason.

- I increased the `eps` parameter of the batch norm layers to about 0.1. This way, if there's too little variation in a minibatch, the values won't necessarily explode.
- I did residual scaling of 0.1 for my residual blocks, basically multiplying the residual by 0.1 before adding to the skip connection.
- I lowered the learning rate to 1e-4.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering the learning rate is a good suggestion, but it decreased the spike intensity instead removing them.

What worked in my case was adding a few BatchNormalization layers which helped stabilise the loss and the training.

I was using the Adam optimiser, and had a batch size of 32 in my case. The last batch with potentially few examples is dropped during my training round so it's not something that could have caused it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).